# Enabling nullable reference type warnings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-5, nullable-reference-types

I have a MSTest project file that includes the following section:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <Nullable>annotations</Nullable>
  <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
  <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But I am not getting nullable reference type warnings.

However, if I add the following to my code:

```
#nullable enable

#nullable restore
```

Then the code between those two lines ***does*** show nullable reference warnings.

How can I enable these warnings for my entire project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your project file first sets the property to "enable", then changes it to "annotations" - get rid of the `<Nullable>annotations</Nullable>` line in the project file and it will be enabled.

(I *suspect* it defaults to enabled for .NET 5.0 projects anyway, but it does no harm to explicitly set it to "enable".)

Comment: How lucky to have Jon Skeet happen by on a Saturday morning and help me (again). Yes, I saw an example that used both and that's what I've been doing. But in the other cases, I see I put `annotations` first so it didn't matter. Clearly, I do not have a firm understanding of these two settings. Thanks!

Comment: Checking further, it does appear that the `enabled` setting is required. At least, with my configuration.